# rails Finding and updating a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model:

ChatStatus with the following fields (ID, user_id, status, thread_id)

What I want to do is update the user's status from 'unread' to 'read'

What I have to do is:

```
@chat = current_user.chats.where(:thread_id => 23)
```

23 came from an AJAX post. I then have to do:

```
@chat.status = 'read'
@chat.save
```

That hits the database twice. I'm wondering is there a way to do that all in request to the database? Something like:

```
@chat = current_user.chats.where(:thread_id => 23).status = 'read'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
current_user.chats.where(:thread_id => 23).update_all(:status => 'read')
```